# How to convert Obj-C code into a library

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

I have 3 apps written in Obj-C that I want to modify and convert to libraries, so I can use them in a Monotouch app.

Where do I find docs that tell me how to take Obj-C code and turn it into libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a file called `lib1.m`

You will first have to compile it as object code. For instance:

```
gcc -Wall -framework Cocoa -o lib1.o lib1.m
```

That will create `lib1.o`

Then you'll have to decide wether you want a static or dynamic library.

To build a static library, you'll need a library object first:

```
glibtool --quiet --mode=compile gcc -o lib1.lo -c lib1.c
```

Then you can create the static library from the library archive:

```
glibtool --quiet --mode=link gcc -o lib1.la -c lib1.lo
```

To build a dynamic library:

```
libtool -dynamic -flat_namespace -lSystem -undefined suppress -macosx_version_min 10.6 -install_name /usr/local/lib/lib1.dylib -o lib1.dylib lib1.o
```

Note that for dynamic libraries, you must provide the install path when creating the library.